# how to make position of view dynamic using constrants in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout

I am developing an app in which i am showing a image view.There are some red dots on image which are **UIButton**.When user tap on button then image should zoom.For that i have added a scroll view with constraints as below

[image: ScrollView]

Inside scroll view i have imageview

[image: ImageView]

Now i when my screen size changes then image size also changes.I have added a UIButton as red dot.I have given it's constraints horizontal & vertical line.

[image]

Now when device size change then button position on image also change.
What i want the button position should also be same on all device even if the image size grows.Please tell me how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

- Add the button on top of the UIImage View
- then add constraints by dragging from the button to the image.
- first put two constraints for leading space from UIImageView and top
  space from UIImageView to be a constant or standard depending on ur
  needs.
- It would look something like this as ur code..
  button.top = image.top
  button.leading = image.leading
- adding these two constraints will do ur work.
- If u want to fix    the size of the button u need to add hieght and
  width constraints.
  ill attach an image on how it looks like[image]

here the weather icon is the image and i m setting constraints on the button
(remove the constraints for trailing and bottom)

> To place the button according to the image

1. set the image to a known size say 100 x 100
   and then place the button at the required place.
2. now check the distance from the top of the image to the button.
   ex. if it is say 12 then ur ratio will be 12:100
3. now set a constant (`button.top`) to 12.
4. so now if the height changes to say 200 multiply it by the ratio
   i.e `image.height* 12/100`
   in the given example `constant = 200(new image hieght) *(12/100)(ratio)` = 24
   so the new distance of the `button.top = 24`

Comment: I want to keep postion of button fix.I mean if red dot on cloud in image then it should be on cloud on every device it should not move

Comment: ohh so ur image is in the scroll view correct??
so u just need to drag and drop the button over the uiimage.
and then drag the mouse pointer from the button to uiimage.
ull get the options. i will edit my answer for that.

Comment: Yes.But issue is if the image increase in size then the position of red dot button change on image.say if the red dot image is on cloud on one device then it be same on that postion on another device

Comment: ohh then ull have to set constraints programatically.
and see what ur image ratio is. depending on the ratio u can set constant values to the constraints....
for that take a reference image resolution and check what the button position values are....
and depending on how much ur image increases or decreases in size adjust the button accordingly

Comment: Okay.I knew this is the solution i thought i could make this process easier by using some other methods.Programmatically then i have to set constraints diffrent for each device.

Comment: nope... just calculate the ratio and multiply the original constant value by that ratio for width and height.... thats it..
i dont know if theres a better way to do it

Comment: how to calculate the ratio & multiply that with constant .can you give me example.I am not clear on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103461/discussion-between-shravan-and-techguy).

Comment: i can't give top space from image because view is on the image so i can't give x position to that.

Answer (score 0):

Like a view, you can drag and drop the constraints into the viewController.m file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myLayoutConstraint;
```

where you can manipulate programmatically:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.myLayoutConstraint.constant = 10;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //handle completion
}];
```